# Why does my laptop run this code example from official documentation forever?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I'm trying to run this code example from `multiprocessing`s official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). My Python is from `Anaconda3-2020.07-Windows-x86_64.exe`.

[image]

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

Could you please explain why my laptop runs this code forever without stopping?

Answer (score 1):

May be because, you are using python 2. I tried it with Python 3 and getting the output as expected. In Python2, It throws below error ...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 7, in <module>
    with Pool(5) as p:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Comment: Sadly, my Python is 3.8.3.

Comment: My Python is from `Anaconda3-2020.07-Windows-x86_64.exe`.